# Do the original English rule books have the same contents per page number as the French-translated ones?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, translations, french

I've ordered the official [French translation of the DMG](https://www.black-book-editions.fr/produit.php?id=4436) (edited by Black Book Editions) and I was wondering if the page numbers remain the same.

I can read that the book has 320 pages as listed in the detailed info on the book, but is the content on those pages equal to the original one?

More generally, do the three core books (MM, DMG, PHB) all retain the same information on the same page numbers as the original English?

I'm most concerned about this for use in the RPG Stack. There's often some physical reference to a page number in the original books.

Comment: I own the PHB in both languages so I could check that, would that help ? (I only have french MM and DMG though)

Comment: @PierreCathé Of course it would. As Revolver_Ocelot already stated that these books contain the same content, you may add a comment to the answer backing it with your verification or create a new answer if you disagree with it.

Comment: If there's no new answer until then I'll check this week-end (I don't have the english book on hand)

Comment: @PierreCathé I suggest checking a random page on spell descriptions. It has the most potential for differences (for example, spells might be ordered alphabetically in French instead of retaining their English order)

Comment: Yeah I've already got a partial answer from my memories but I'll post it only after verifying it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The PHB has everything at the same page, except for sorted stuff

I grabbed my French and my English PHBs and compared : every chapter starts at the same page, every rule is at the same page, every table is at the same page.

However, anything that's sorted in alphabetical order in the English version is also sorted in alphabetical order in the French version, which means it'll be at different pages. This includes races, classes, backgrounds, feats and spells.

Sadly I can't speak for the DMG or MM as I only own those in French.

Comment: This is slightly annoying. Luckily in those cases, page number is likely to go together with a name you can use to still find what you need. It seems that references to other rules are going to be still usable.

Answer (score 8):

I did some research and I found what appears to be [a preview of a French version of the PHB translated by Black Book Editions](https://paradoxetemporel.fr/10202-dungeons-dragons-5e-ed-players-handbook-le-guide-de-reference-des-joueurs-de-dd-chez-black-book-edition.html).

It contains a few images of book pages. Studying those, I found that they contain the exactly same content as the English version.

I would say that translators did a great job and page numbers are consistent with the English version, at least up to page 185.